# A django page which controls a numerical model

Tags: python, django, forms, object, external

I am creating a webpage that is going to be used as an interface for a numerical model (controlled by a python wrapper). The idea is that the user can input parameters into a form on the page, which creates an object with all the necessary information to run the numerical model. This is my forms.py

```
from django import forms
from models import ChemRun

class ChemRunForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
            model = ChemRun
            fields = ('owner', 'title', 'times_max','temperature_min', 'temperature_max')
```

my models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class ChemRun(models.Model):
    owner           =       models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    title           =       models.CharField(max_length=200)
    created_date    =       models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    times_max       =       models.DecimalField(max_digits=99, decimal_places=20, null=True)
    temperature_min =       models.DecimalField(max_digits=99, decimal_places=20, null=True)
    temperature_max =       models.DecimalField(max_digits=99, decimal_places=20, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return self.title
```

and the HTML code for the form to start a new model

```
<header>
    <h2>Start a new model</h2>
</header>
<section>
    <form action='/chemrun/create/' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
        <table>
            {{form.as_table}}
        </table>

        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="New run">
    </form>
</section>
```

**Now to my first question:**
 How do I catch this object which contains all the model parameters and put it into a queue from which these objects are sent to the numerical model, and I want it to be able to handle multiple cores (e.g. I can specify that X of these models are running simultaneously). How would I handle this?

**Second question:**
Afterwards this numerical code will create a SQLite database with the results. How can I make this webapp be alerted when models are finish and then send an email to a user to let them know their data is ready?

If you can, please explain the steps, since I am still a bit of a newbie on Django, and I prefer to understand what I am doing and why :)

Many thanks for the help!

Comment: There are too many valid ways to solve this kind of problems, but basically you want an async message queue. Celery is the most obvious candidate here but you may want to have a look at huey and zero-mq  too.

Comment: I have looked at Celery, but I am still not understanding as to how I would send an object containing all necessary information and then run a python code inside it.